# how to use the if statement in scheme programming?

Tags: scheme

I just started learning the scheme language and below is a question that I stuck a little bit(Is there anything wrong with my code cuz the error message is kinda weird)

```
Prompt: Define a procedure over-or-under which takes in a number x and a number y and returns the following:

-1 if x is less than y
0 if x is equal to y
1 if x is greater than y

What I've tried so far is :

(define (over-or-under x y)
  (if (< x y)
    -1)
  (if (= x y)
    0)
  (if (> x y)
    1)
)

The error message is :
scm> (load-all ".")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  0     (adder 8)
Error: str is not callable: your-code-here

scm> (over-or-under 5 5)

# Error: expected
#     0
# but got
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `if` is:

```
(if condition expression1 expression2)
```

and its value is the value of expression1 when the condition is true, otherwise it is the value of expression2.

In your function instead you use:

```
(if condition expression1)
```

and this is not allowed. Note, moreover that the three `if`s one after the other are executed sequentially and only the value of the last one is actually used, as the value returned by the function call.

A way of solving this problem is using a “cascade” of `if`:

```
(define (over-or-under x y)
  (if (< x y)
      -1
      (if (= x y)
          0
          1)))
```

Note that the proper alignment make clear the order of execution of the different expressions. If `(< x y)` is true than the value -1 is the result of the `if`, but, since it is the last expression of the function, it is also the value of the function call. If this is not true, we execute the “inner” `if`, checking if x is equal to y, and so on. Note also that in the third case is not necessary to check if x is greater than y, since it is surely true, given that x is not less than y, neither equal to y.

Finally, note that the “cascade” of x is so common that in scheme exists a more syntactically convient way of expressing it with the specific `cond` expression:

```
(cond (condition1 expression1)
      (condition2 expression2)
      ...
      (else expressionN))
```

so you could rewrite the function is this way:

```
(define (over-or-under x y)
  (cond ((< x y) -1)
        ((= x y) 0)
        (else 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful!